# Write data in files from array of structures using pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to rewrite text in files, changing first line by +1(that holds number of struct saved in `igraci.txt`) This part is working fine. Then rewrite all text that was there before(This is also working fine) and in the end add 2 new lines in text. Problem is in the last code i wrote here

These are some global variables that I am having problem with and strcture

```
int RijeciBroj = 0;
int IgraciBroj = 0;
typedef struct Igrac
{
    char ime[20];
    int brojPoena;
};
```

This is method for allocating memmory for structures having in mind that one strcture is going to be added

```
struct Igrac* napraviProstor(int n) {
    IgraciBroj = n; //here I try to give global new value
    printf("U NAPRAVI PROSTOR : %d", IgraciBroj); // Here i get -9282928

    return (struct Igrac*) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(struct Igrac));
}
```

This is method that is reading text from file and storing it in allocated memory

```
void ucitajIgrace(struct Igrac *arr) {
    static const char filename[] = "igraci.txt";
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[20];
        int n;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
        int i = -1;
        int k = 0;
        fgets(line, 20, file);
        while (fgets(line, 20, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {
            line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
            i++;
            if (i == 0) {
                strcpy((arr + k)->ime, line);


            }
            if (i == 1) {
                (arr + k)->brojPoena = atol(line);

                k++;
                i = -1;
            }







        }

        printf("Igraca: %d", IgraciBroj); //here i get -9892827280


        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        perror(filename);
    }
}
```

Main method

```
int main()
{
    int o;
    Igrac *igr;
    FILE *file1;
    file1 = fopen("igraci.txt", "r");
    if (file1 != NULL)
    {
        char line[20];

        fscanf(file1, "%d", &o); //first line is number of structs
        igr = napraviProstor(o);

        ucitajIgrace(igr);
    }


    pocniIgru(rijeci,igr); //ignore rijeci that is another array that is working perfect and has nothing to do with my problem
    return 0;
}
```

This is method where I have problem

```
void pocniIgru(char** rijeci, struct Igrac *igraci) {
    int dobijeni[5] = {}; //array that is saving random numbers so they don't repeat
    int brojac1 = 0; //used for index of dobijeni[5]
    char srpska[30]; // for user input
    char ime[20]; //for users name that we are going to store in igraci.txt
    int poeni = 0; //number of points
    bool moze;  //boolean for loop control
    printf("Pocinje igra\n");
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    int pitanje; // for random number that we are going to get
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        moze = true;
    LOOP:do {
        srand(time(NULL));
        pitanje = rand() % RijeciBroj-1; //random number between 0 - global variable here global variable is working fine!
         if (pitanje % 2 != 0) {
             pitanje++; // I need even number and 0 is accepted
         }


         for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
             if (dobijeni[k] == pitanje) { //checking if we arleay had that number
                 goto LOOP; // goto LOOP if we had that number so we pick another
             }

         }

         dobijeni[brojac1] = pitanje; //storing that number in loop for later check so it won't repeat
         moze = false; // do-while stops
         brojac1++;




     } while (moze);

        printf("Engleska rijec je: %s", rijeci[pitanje]); //get word from array
        printf("Unesite rijec na srpskom jeziku: ");
        scanf("%30s", srpska); //user input for comparing
        strtok(rijeci[pitanje + 1], "\n"); //we need to remove newline
        if (strcmp(rijeci[pitanje+1], srpska) == 0) { //cheking if next word is same with user input
            poeni += 2;
            printf("Tacno! Vas broj peona je %d\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", poeni);
        }
        else {
            poeni -= 1;
            if (brojac != 5) {
                printf("Greska! Vas broj peona je %d\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", poeni);
            }

        }

        }

    printf("Ukupan broj poena je: %d\n", poeni);
    printf("Unesite svoje ime: "); //Enter your name
    scanf("%s", ime); //get name
    if (strcmp(ime, "")) { //check if it's empty
        IgraciBroj += 1; //global variable +1 for rewriting in file
        strcpy((igraci + IgraciBroj)->ime, ime); //save name in char* struct in last place that is empty

        (igraci + IgraciBroj)->brojPoena = poeni; //save points in char* struct in last place that is empty
        printf("%s osvojili ste %d poena", (igraci + IgraciBroj)->ime, (igraci + IgraciBroj)->brojPoena); //Here i get normal result and name
        FILE *file1;
        file1 = fopen("igraci.txt", "w");
        if (file1 != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(file1, "%d\n", IgraciBroj);
            for (int broj = 0; broj < IgraciBroj; broj++) {
                fprintf(file1, "%s\n", (igraci + broj)->ime); //Problem !! I get some lines before name in file example(----------Name)
                fprintf(file1, "%d\n", (igraci + broj)->brojPoena); //Problem !! I get some number like -9899887
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `LOOP:do` this is bad

Comment: @KamilCuk Why it's working perfect ?

Comment: Why call `srand()` in a loop?

Comment: I would advise to never use goto, unless you really know how to use it and you use it for "exception" handling. You can `break;` + `if (k==5) continue;` there. You find many sources on the net about why goto is bad.

Comment: 1. Unless you create some smaller, reproducible example you won't get much help here. 2. `// Here i get -9282928`. Have you checked what the value of `n` in `napraviProstor` is and what the value of `o` after `scanf` in `main()` is? Are you sure that scanf didn't read that value? Posting the content of `igraci.txt` would make this issue reproducible

Comment: @KamilCuk It's good in those parts you asked for. In `igraci.txt` I have first line 4(number of structs) then next line is playername and next line is points of that player and that 4 times

Comment: I would recommand using vocabulary according to the language you are using. For C, that would be talking about functions instead of methods. 

That being said, most people will still understand.

Comment: I got it to work by changing `void pocniIgru(char** rijeci, struct Igrac *igraci)` to `void pocniIgru(char** rijeci, struct Igrac *igraci, int numOfPlayers)` and giving function information about how many structs we have in file and using variable `numOfPlayers` instead global variable. My code is working now but i want to know if someone know to explain why this code above is not ?

Comment: Any information on how you were having issue with the old code ?

Comment: @Alceste_ 2 new lines in file were not saved corectly. First one (expected: Name) were saved as -----Name and second one (expected: number of points that user got example:6) was saved as -9877765567

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct Igrac
{
    char ime[20];
    int brojPoena;
};`  this 'typedef' is missing the 'name' for the typedef.  So how do you expect to be able to reference the typedef?

Comment: None of the posted code compiles!  When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: @user3121023 you are right! I cannot belive i changed my code because of that. I was pointing to index out of bounds tottaly forgetting I have arleady set index to last. Thank you very much